# Is it possible to create a form for static pages and storing the data in User table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am creating an application where User can change  background-color of page, title of page and font of text in page, and it should be single page application, where changes should persist with the user session. I have created authentication using devise and can signup and login the page.I have created a static_pages controller where I have created form and using this form to store the value in User database and now when I am trying to submit the form I am getting the error{No Route match[POST]}, My form looks like this:

/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user do |u| %>
 <br > 
 <p>
    <%= u.label :title %><br>
    <%= u.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :description %><br>
    <%= u.text_field :description %>
  </p>

  <p> <%= u.label :back_ground_color %><br>
    <select name="back-ground" id="bgcolor">
        <option value="1">Orange</option>
        <option value="2">Green</option>
        <option value="3">Blue</option>
        <option value="4">Pink</option>
        <option value="5">Yellow</option>
        <option value="6">White</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <div style="background: #{current_user.bg_color};"></div>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :font %><br>
    <select name="font" id="font">
        <option value="1">Times new Roman</option>
        <option value="2">Calibri</option>
        <option value="3">fantasy</option>
        <option value="4">serif</option>
    </select>
  </p>

 <br >
  <p>
    <%= u.submit %>
  </p>
  <hr >
  <div style="background-color:#{current_user.font.nil? ? '#FFFFFF' : current_user.font}">
    This is the changes made in background
  </div>

  <div style="background-color:#{current_user.bgcolor.nil? ? '#FFFFFF' : current_user.bgcolor}">

  </div>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  post '/static_pages/home'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'static_pages#home', as: :authenticated_root
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

I have user table where I have created extra column for title, bg-color, font and description and trying to store the record.

Now when I try to submit the form I am getting `No route matches [POST]` error. Please let me know your suggestions and solution.

Comment: what do you expect this line `post  '/static_pages/home'` to do?

Comment: Since I have created a controller for static_pages and given index as home so in routes.rb you will get {get 'static_pages/home'}. even after removing the line I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done rails `POSTs` via this format of routing declaration:

```
match 'static_pages/home/' => 'static_pages#home', :via => :post
```

where the first part is the URL path (plus any variable, if needed) and the second part is the controller method to match it to, with `:via => :post` indicating too use POST instead of GET.

Take a look at [Rails routing guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) as well.

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried all possible permutation and combination on this

Comment: I feel I am doing mistake in designing the application itself , precisely doing mistake in defining form properly.